# Проверка срабатывания события сlick

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

У меня вот такая задача, необходимо проверить, было ли сработано событие ***click***.
При клике на `$('.leftCol div.enabled')` у меня всплывает окно, при наведении срабатывает `mouseleave()` (когда курсор выходит за пределы блока `$('.choiceOfDishes')` блок скрывается).

Мне необходимо сделать:

- Если  не сработало событие ***click*** на `$('.dish')` и курсор перешел за пределы блока `$('.choiceOfDishes')`, то убрать активность кнопки `$('.leftCol div')`.
- Суть вопроса, как проверить, было ли сработано событие ***click*** на  `$('.dish')`?

```js
$('.leftCol div.enabled').live('click',function(){
              $(this).addClass('active');
              $("#"+$(this).attr('arrow')).show();  
            $('.choiceOfDishes').mouseleave(function(){
                      $('.choiceOfDishes').hide();
                            }); 
         $('.dish').click(function(){
           Cufon.replace($("div[arrow="+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+"]").text($(this).text()));      $("div[arrow="+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+"]").next().addClass('enabled');
           $(this).parent().parent().hide();
          });
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

Создавай переменную `var wasclicked = false` при клике `return wasClicked = true`, а когда курсор выйдет из области делай проверку на значение, если true, то значит был клик, если так false и остался, то не было клика